# Issue setting up phpMyAdmin on Max OS X 10.7

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I'm really new to the world of PHP/setting up a SQL database.

I am trying to set up phpMyAdmin on my Mac, but I am getting stuck on one of the final steps.

The methodology that I use this [link](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/)

My issue arises when I hit the Installing phpMyAdmin.

I cannot access the `http://localhost/~INSERTMYUSERNAMEHERE/phpmyadmin/setup/` page.

Have I missed a step?  Am I doing something terribly wrong?

As a note, I used [this](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-php-mysql-apache-on-os-x-10-6/) to install and configure apache/mysql.  Is this guide missing a crucial step?

EDIT: I wasn't locating my configuration file in the highest level directory.  It remained in the config folder...I simply moved it out and into the highest level of directory and everything worked extremely well.

Comment: can you access http://localhost/~INSERTMYUSERNAMEHERE/ ? did you start apache?

Comment: I can access localhost/~myusername

I am fairly certain that I started Apache.  In terminal restarted it using the graceful command.

Is there anyway to be sure that I have apache started?

Comment: If you can access that url in your browser, then apache is running. What error do you get when you visit the phpMyAdmin page?

Comment: So I've managed to get myself to the phpMyAdmin.

I cannot setup phpMyAdmin.  So by following the directions in the guide that I listed, I cannot access localst/~myusername/phpmyadmin/setup

I get the following error:

"NOT FOUND The requested URL /~myusername/phpmyadmin/setup was not found on this server."

Comment: The URL will be case sensitive. Is setup a directory? Make sure it's there.

Comment: I have tried the URL many different ways.

I think my problem lies in my config folder.

I am unsure of how to set up this folder...that is i download phpmyadmin.gz from the php site. >> Do I need to place this file somewhere?

Also, how would I go about making setup a directory?

I am VERY new at this by the way, thank you for all of the help.  I only have experience as a SQL user

Comment: I see you marked this question as solved through the title. Can you post your solution and mark it as the solution so that the question can be closed?